# What is the average distance from the base of a rectangular pyramid to its apex?

Tags: geometry

What is the formula for the average distance from the base of a rectangular pyramid to its apex? For example, if the base of the pyramid is 30 feet by 8 feet, and the height of the pyramid is 12 feet, then what is the average distance from the base to the apex?

Assume that the pyramid is symmetric.

Comment: I think one has to assume something like that the apex lies directly above the center of the rectangular base. Otherwise if the apex is off center by a certain unknown amount, the average can't be found uniquely. Also, to be clear, you mean the average distance from a point in the base to the apex, correct?

Comment: @coffeemath Right, if you were to compute the distance between every point in the base and the apex, what would be the average of those distances.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. What have you done so far?

Comment: Have you tried setting up an integral? For example make the center of the rectangular base at $(0,0,0)$ and the apex at $(0,0,h),$ then define the rectangle as say $-a \le x \le a$ and $-b \le y \le b$...

Comment: @rogerl The last time I did "homework" was 30 years ago when Ronald Reagan was president.

Comment: @TylerDurden Me too. (My bad).

Comment: @coffeemath: I've set up the integral in Mathematica and it's still chugging away trying to solve it. The numerical result for the dimensions in the question is about 14.8171 though.

Comment: @Rahul What was your integrand? I'd have thought it had to be just a quadratic under a squareroot, and would be solvable once put into iterated integral format. So I guess after one of the iterations the intermediate result is difficult?

Comment: The integral is pretty ugly; converting it to polar coordinates helps some, but it still does not have a simple closed form. Integrating over the portion of the base in the first quadrant (assuming the center of the base is at the origin) gives $$20 \sqrt{385}+576 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{16}{5 \sqrt{385}}\right)-576 \cot ^{-1}\left(9 \sqrt{\frac{5}{77}}\right)+\frac{896}{3} \tanh ^{-1}\left(3 \sqrt{\frac{5}{77}}\right)+\frac{3285}{2} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{4}{\sqrt{385}}\right)$$

Comment: @roger1 Yes I also found it was not doable by maple in rectangular form, and thought of using polar. Interesting that it does have a closed polar form, even if involved!

Comment: @coffeemath: The integral is just $\int_{-\ell/2}^{\ell/2}\int_{-b/2}^{b/2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+h^2}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$, but Mathematica hasn't found a closed form for it. When I replaced $\ell$, $b$, and $h$ with the numbers, though, I got $$80 \sqrt{385}-3285 \log (369)+6570 \log \left(4+\sqrt{385}\right)-2304 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{5}{77}}\right)+\frac{3584}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{3 \sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}}{4}\right).$$ This is not yet divided by the area of the base. Quite possibly it is equal to rogerl's expression times $4$.